# No existing drivers for Monoprice 8x6?

Tags: debian, drivers, tablet

I have been looking around all day to get my "Monoprice 8x6" MP Select USB Graphic Tablet" set up and running on Debian 10. I have looked around at DIGImend and evdev, but so far I have no results.

xinput list

```
⎜   ↳ UGTABLET TABLET GT8607 Mouse              id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

No luck using digimend-kernel-drivers (version 9). The tablet lights up and connects, and "works" by being able to click, but not move the cursor.

Update: Still cannot get it working, however, upon further research I found list-props.

xinput list-props "UGTABLET TABLET GT8607 Mouse"

```
evice 'UGTABLET TABLET GT8607 Mouse':
    Device Enabled (155):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (289):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (290):       0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (291):        0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (292):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (293):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (294): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (295): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (296):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (297):        0
    libinput Accel Speed (298):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (299):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (300):        1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (301):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (302):   1, 0
    libinput Calibration Matrix (307):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (308):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (303):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (304):     0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (274):     1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (275):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (276):        0, 0
    Device Node (277):      "/dev/input/event13"
    Device Product ID (278):        8569, 113
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (305):       <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (306):       1
```